# Facebook login using OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

1. I want people to log in to my site with their Facebook accounts.
2. I need to pull some info from their Facebook profile and add it to my site's database

I have tried using the OAuth 2.0 method which makes a redirect to this url

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
   &state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

I successfully authenticated the user but now the main problem arose. How do I access the data which is sent as response all I can see is a `GET` variable named `code` and some long text. How do I convert to usable data?

I use php for my website

Comment: Did you take a look in the extensive documentation on developers.facebook.com?

There you can find a working example in php to retrieve user info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Answer (score 4):

Exchange the code for a user access token

Once the user has authorized your app, you should make a server side request to exchange the code returned above for a user access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

The client_secret parameter must be the App Secret as shows in your app's settings. The body of the response to this request will be a url encoded string of the form:

```
access_token=USER_ACESS_TOKEN&expires=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
```

You should parse this string and use the access_token value to make requests to the Graph API. You should also persist the access token in your database in order to make further requests to the API without having to re-authenticate the user.

Once the access token expiry time is reached, the token will become invalid and can no longer be used in requests to the API. To obtain a new user access token, you must pass the user through this flow again. However, if the user has not deauthorized your app and you're asking for no permissions beyond those which the user has already granted your application, then no dialog will be displayed and the user will be transparently redirected to your redirect_uri with a fresh code which can be exchanged for a fresh user access token.

If there is an issue exchanging the code for a user access token, the authorization server will issue an HTTP 400 and return the error as a JSON object in the body of the response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating verification code."
   }
}
```

For further reference checkout http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

Making requests to the Graph API

With a valid user access token, you can make requests to read and write data from the Graph API. A common first request would be to get the basic information (including the id and name) of the user who just authenticated your app:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: So the response you're talking about, what is the response format is it a GET response or do have to use some other way to parse the data

Comment: the code is available as a $_GET['code'] variable. Just exchange the code for access_token and you're ready to make API calls to get user data

Answer (score 1):

There is an [official SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) for php from Facebook. Which makes life easier.

Check this [sample code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)

Answer (score 1):

In OAuth 2.0 with facebook, the overall concept is simple as follows.

Step 1. Obtain "Authorization Code" by a GET request

```
request URI: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
Params:
    response_type=code
    client_id={add your "App id" got by registering app}
    redirect_uri={add redirect uri defined at the registration of app}
    scope={add the scope needed in your app}
Headers: None
```

Step 2. Obtain the "Access Token" by sending the authorization code as a POST request

```
request URI: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
Params:
    grant_type=authorization_code
    client_id=<add your "App id" got by registering app>
    redirect_uri=<add redirect uri defined at the registration of app>
    code=<obtained authorization code from previous step>
Headers:
    Authorization:Basic encode <App Id:App Secret> with base64 
    Content-Type:application/json
```

Step 3. Use the access token got from above step and retrieve user resources

Comment: Also make sure to read the facebooks documentation because they update the changes gradually and some gets depricated