# Implementing Facebook login into existing login system - user verification

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, authentication

I want to impelemt a facebook login into my existing login system.

It's important to me that a local account (on my db) is created from the facebook data.

The JS SDK of FB is already implemented - so I can give the permission to login and will receive something like this:

```
Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}
authResponse: ObjectaccessToken: "<token>"
expiresIn: 4134
signedRequest: "<Token>"
userID: "<userid>" 
Objectstatus: "connected"
```

My Idea was to take the email give from facebook (already working) and create an account base on this.

My problem now is - that it would be easy for me to login everybody who gets status connected from facebook api call. However, I think this would be pretty insecure.

I'm looking for a way to store a token or an ID i could use (together with the email) to ensure that the currently logged in user has the email which will be used to log him in.

Comment: Look at Facebook oAuth - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook login using OAuth 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016676/facebook-login-using-oauth-2-0)

Comment: FYI: You will not get an email address for every Facebook user (f.e. for those that registered for FB using their mobile.)